# Why point exclamation is not display?

Tags: extjs

In my form panel, i have some fields who are required .

I explain :

If user clik on tree , if is directory any fields are required but for leaf ( file )
somes fields are required .

I add allowBlank properties like this :

```
Ext.apply(cmp,{
    allowBlank : false
});
```

That works but i haven't got the exclamation point on my panel !

You can see result on this picture : [image: field allowBlank : true]

An idea ? 
The exclamation.gif is well declared on sencha's css and it is present on the extjs 's folder.

Thanks lot :)

Comment: have you initialised quicktips?

Comment: yes ! 
 `Ext.QuickTips.init();`

Strange ... >>

Comment: does it work if you explicitly configure the field to rather than using the `Ext.apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your QuickTips config... and underneath the `Ext.QuickTips.init()` call add...

`Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';`